# Function which work when I get data statically, but when I get data from an API, the function works but at the end, everything is erased

Tags: angular, spring, typescript

I try to draw some lines with a function called Draw. The function works well, and when I create an array with some data, the lines are drawn perfectly.
When I get data from a REST API, when I execute step by step, I can see that the lines are well drawn, but, after the last iteration, everything is erased.

Here is my HTML :

```
<table *ngIf="listeFamilles">
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let f of listeFamilles">
      <th style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px;">{{ f.nom }}</th>
      <td  id="{{f.nom}}"  style="vertical-align: top;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is where I call my function, in the component :
(listeFamilles is declared at the top of the component, and his type is any)

```
export class EncoursComponent implements AfterViewInit{

  //Variables du controleur

constructor(private serviceFam: FamillesService) {
    this.getFamilles();
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.serviceFam.getAllFamilles()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.listeFamilles = data;
        console.log(this.listeFamilles);
        for (let f of this.listeFamilles) {
          //console.log(this.listeAffaires._embedded.affaires[0]);
          console.log(f.nom);
          this.draw("#" + f.nom, this.arriel1, {dateDimension: false, color: "teal", labelFormat: "%Y"})
          alert('test');
        }
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

}
```

This is my function in my service :

```
public getAllFamilles(){
    return this.httpClient.get(this.host+"/listFamilles")
  }
```

And this is what I get in this.listeFamilles :

```
(12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, nom: "ARRIEL1", couleur: "32cd32"}
1: {id: 2, nom: "ARRIEL2", couleur: "2b78e4"}
2: {id: 3, nom: "TURMO", couleur: "ffffff"}
3: {id: 4, nom: "MAKILA1", couleur: "999999"}
4: {id: 5, nom: "ARRIUS2F", couleur: "ffff00"}
5: {id: 6, nom: "ARRIUS1", couleur: "ff00ff"}
6: {id: 7, nom: "ARRIUS2", couleur: "ff9900"}
7: {id: 8, nom: "ASTAZOU3", couleur: "ffff00"}
8: {id: 9, nom: "RTM322", couleur: "351c75"}
9: {id: 11, nom: "MAKILA2", couleur: "999999"}
10: {id: 12, nom: "ASTAZOU4", couleur: "ffff00"}
11: {id: 13, nom: "ASTAZOU14", couleur: "ffff00"}
length: 12
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: What do you get in this.listeFamilles
?

Comment: @MichałTkaczyk I have edited my post with the content of this.listeFamilles